# how to do search with api and re render the elements with the api response data if the search value changes react native (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

### Example Code

```
const MainScreen = ({route,navigation}) => {
 const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [orderdetails, setOrderdetails] = useState([]);
  const [ordertracking, setOrdertracking] = useState([]);
  const [mergeddata, setMergeddata] = useState([]);
  const [mobilsearch, setMobilsearch] = useState([]);
  


  useEffect(async () => {
    try{
     var res1 = await fetch('first api mobileno=%2B911234567890')
     var data1 = await res1.json()
     var res2 = await fetch('second api mobileno=%2B911234567890')
     var data2 = await res2.json()
     setOrderdetails(data1)
     setOrdertracking(data2)
     var res = []
     for(let d1 of data1.content){
       res.push({...d1,...data2.content.find(d2=>d2.orderid==d1.orderid)})
       
     }
     console.log(res)
     setMergeddata(res);
    }catch(e){
      console.error(e)
    }finally{
     setLoading(false)
    }
   }, []);
  



  //console.log(ordertracking);
  return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1,  paddingBottom:14, backgroundColor:"white",paddingTop:3 }}>
        <View style={{width:'100%', height:40,borderBottomWidth:1,borderTopWidth:1,bordercolor:'black', flexDirection:'row',marginLeft:'auto',marginRight:'auto'}}>
        
        <TextInput 
          style={{width:'70%'}}
          maxLength={10}
         
           placeholder='Enter the Phone Number'
           keyboardType="numeric"
           value={mobilsearch}
           
        onChangeText={setMobilsearch}
      />
      <TouchableHighlight 
     onPress={() => { 'Need to render re render every search while' }}
     >
     <Image
       
     source={require('./components/image/loupe.png')} 
                        
                        />
     </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        
        <View style={{paddingLeft: 14, paddingRight:14, marginTop:5}}>
      {isLoading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> : 
      ( <View >
          <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={mergeddata}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View>
              <Text>{item.orderid}</Text>
             </View>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
  
}
```

### Description

1. Up in the example code for a react native app I have been fetching two json data from two api response and then merge them which has a same value and store them in mergeddata
2. I have been fetching api with the mobile number
3. And then display the merged data in a flatlist

### Needed

1. When i load the app i send the mobile number as a string it works fine
2. I need to get mobile mobile number from  and storing them in 'mobilsearch'
3. When i click the search button in 'onPress' i need to pass the mobile number to the api from textinput and fetch response from api and then show the result in a flatlist for the entered mobile number
4. Every time i click search button i need to repeat the process for every time click search button
5. Pass the mobile number at the end of the api as a parameter , the mobile number which i get from textinput and display in a flatlist with the new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey buddy i'm not so sure that i understand your problem.
but as for now you have no onPress actions, i think what you need to do is taking all of the fetching from useEffect, make a function =>

```
async function handleFetch(){
try{
     var res1 = await fetch('first api mobileno=%2B911234567890')
     var data1 = await res1.json()
     var res2 = await fetch('second api mobileno=%2B911234567890')
     var data2 = await res2.json()
     setOrderdetails(data1)
     setOrdertracking(data2)
     var res = []
     for(let d1 of data1.content){
       res.push({...d1,...data2.content.find(d2=>d2.orderid==d1.orderid)})
       
     }
     console.log(res)
     setMergeddata(res);

    }
catch(e){
      console.error(e)
    }finally{
     setLoading(false)
    }
}
```

and then use it in the touchableopacity onPress event.
hope this helps, if it dosent kindly send your problem to me again a bit more specific please.

Comment: I can get data with this function but how do i render in a flatlist every time I fetch the data . Every time i search with the mobile number the response will change every time so i have the render the new data

Comment: when using setMergedData it updates mergedata that is rendered on flatlist.
thats what [state, setState] all about.  lets you hook this variable to react state, i recommend reading further on react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html